# ScalaSlickで別名にしたtableを結合したい

Tags: scala, slick

scala初心者です。こういったコミュニティサイトでの質問自体も初めてなので、不備がありましたらその旨も教えてください。

## ■困っていること

SQLでの別名による表結合をどのように表現してよいかわからないです。

### やりたいこと（SQLで表現した場合）

```sql
SELECT
  A.DepartmentCd,
  A.DepartmentName,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  Department A,
  Employee B
WHERE
  A.DepartmentCd = B.DepartmentCd (+)
  A.DepartmentCd = '1000'
GROUP BY
  A.DepartmentCd
```

### scalaで書きかけ

下記①②をどうつなげてよいものか悩んでいます。
①

```
Department.filter(_.Departmentcd === '1000')
```

②

```
Employee.map(_.id.count).first leftjoin Department on (Department.DepartmentCd === Employee.DepartmentCd)
```

## ■環境

scala 2.11.8
postgres 9.5.1
slick <s>2.11</s> 3.1.1
Play Framework

Comment: Slick(Play Framework)のバージョンはいくつでしょうか？Play Frameworkが2.5.xであれば、Slickは3.1かと思いますが。 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりです。
Slickのバージョンは3.1.1でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**回答**

元々のSQLの妥当性は判断しかねますが、下記のように書けば期待しているSQLが発行されるかと思います。

```
def select(): Future[Seq[(String, String, Int)]] = db.run {
  department
    .filter(_.DepartmentCd === "1000")
    .flatMap { d =>
      employee
        .filter(_.DepartmentCd === d.DepartmentCd)
        .map(_ => (d.DepartmentCd, d.DepartmentName))
    }
    .groupBy { case (cd, name) => (cd, name) }
    .map { case ((cd, name), group) => (cd, name, group.length) }
    .result
}
```

実行されるSQL

```sql
select
  x2."DepartmentCd", x2."DepartmentName", count(1)
from
  "Department" x2,
  "Employee" x3
where
  (x2."DepartmentCd" = '1000') and
  (x3."DepartmentCd" = x2."DepartmentCd")
group by x2."DepartmentCd", x2."DepartmentName"
```

---

**蛇足**

Implicit inner joinsの書き方は、公式のドキュメントを参考にすると、下記のようになります。

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html#implicit-inner-joins

```
department
  .flatMap { d =>
    employee
      .filter(_.DepartmentCd === d.DepartmentCd)
      .map(_ => (d.DepartmentCd, d.DepartmentName))
  }
  .result
```

```sql
select
  x2."DepartmentCd", x2."DepartmentName"
from
  "Department" x2,
  "Employee" x3
where
  (x3."DepartmentCd" = x2."DepartmentCd")
```

これに`where DepartmentCd = '1000'`と`group by`の条件をつけたものが回答のコードです。

また、`.groupBy { case (cd, name) => (cd, name) }`は引数の変数をそのまま返しているだけなので、[`identity`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L134)を使用して下記のように書けます。

```
department
  .filter(_.DepartmentCd === "1000")
  .flatMap { d =>
    employee
      .filter(_.DepartmentCd === d.DepartmentCd)
      .map(_ => (d.DepartmentCd, d.DepartmentName))
  }
  .groupBy(identity)
  .map { case ((cd, name), group) => (cd, name, group.length) }
  .result
```